# Codeigniter input class

Tags: codeigniter, get

I am doing a simple little piece of code to grab a get variable.

```
$tab = $this->input->get('tab');
```

But this variable is returning empty. I am calling this in a controller, and in one controller it is working, but another it is not. It is such a small simple piece of code I am not sure what is going wrong.

My url is:

```
http://localhost:8888/opportunities/?tab=Blood%20Drive
```

Even when I do something like this:

```
  log_message("INFO", print_r($this->input->get(), true)
```

The entire get array is empty...

Comment: post the code of the controller that isnt working

Comment: The way to get the entire input is to use `$this->input->get(NULL, False);`